# Firesbase orderByChild doesn't work on timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use orderByChild on timestamp.
But it doesn't work well. They even sort by ascending or descending.

Here is the result :

- First : 1581952308253
- Second: 1581671445437
- Last: 1583254605108

[image]

And here is my code:

```
 toolboxesRef.orderByChild('timestamp').once('value', snapshot => {
    res.json(snapshot.val())
 })
```

I know I could use array to determine the data should sort by ascending or descending.
But know it even doesn't sorting. Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of properties in a JSON object is undefined. So as soon as you call `snapshot.val()`, the order of the child nodes is lost.

To maintain the order, use `snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the child nodes:

```
toolboxesRef.orderByChild('timestamp').once('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    console.log(child.val())
  })
})
```

So if you want to return both keys and values to `res`, you'll want to convert the snapshot into an array:

```
toolboxesRef.orderByChild('timestamp').once('value', snapshot => {
  let response = [];
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    response.push({ key: child.key, value: child.val() });
  })
  res.json(response);
})
```